# Problem when deleting an item from the list when using RecycleView and Diffutils

Tags: android, kotlin

I found a strange behavior of Diffutils during the delete operation from the list. When I delete an element for the first time, everything goes fine. But with the subsequent similar action, not the list item that I click on is deleted, but a completely different one. If, after the first deletion, I try to delete the last element, then the application crashes with an IndexOutOfBoundsException. As if the position argument in the onBindViewHolder adapter method is not updated. Tell me what the problem may be. The code below.

DiffUtilCallback.kt

```
class DiffUtilCallback(
    private val oldList: List<MyItem>,
    private val newList: List<MyItem>
) : DiffUtil.Callback() {

    override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
        return oldList.size
    }

    override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
        return newList.size
    }

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList[oldItemPosition].id == newList[newItemPosition].id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.kt

```
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {

    var myList = listOf<MyItem>()
        set(value) {
            val diffUtil = DiffUtilCallback(field, value)
            val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffUtil)
            field = value
            diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
        }

    var onClickListener: ((MyItem) -> Unit)? = null
    var onLongClickListener: ((MyItem) -> Unit)? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val myItem = myList[position]

        holder.bind(myItem)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            onClickListener?.invoke(myItem)
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
            onLongClickListener?.invoke(myList[position])
            true
        }
    }
}

class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private val myTextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.my_text_view)

    fun bind(myItem: MyItem) {
        myTextView.text = myItem.text
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val myList = mutableListOf(
        MyItem(0, "1"),
        MyItem(1, "2"),
        MyItem(2, "3"),
        MyItem(3, "4"),
        MyItem(4,"5"),
    )

    private var adapter: MyAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)

        adapter = MyAdapter()
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter?.myList = myList.toList()

        adapter?.onLongClickListener = {
            deleteItem(it)
        }

        adapter?.onClickListener = { myItem ->
            Log.d("ITEM", myItem.toString())
        }
    }

    private fun deleteItem(myItem: MyItem) {
        myList.remove(myItem)
        adapter?.myList = myList.toList()
    }
}
```

MyItem.kt

```
data class MyItem(
    val id: Int,
    val text: String
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of `onLongClickListener` being invoked, the position passed to `onBindViewHolder` and the actual position of the item in the list are not the same, because you previously already modified the list. To fix just this, call `onLongClickListener?.invoke(myItem)`